# Android webview delete single HttpOnly Cookie only

Tags: android, xamarin, android-webview, httponly

How can I delete an httpOnly cookie from android webView cookiemanager without deleting all other cookies?

GetCookie does not return HTTPOnly cookies and so I can not set it to expired.

I need cookies from other sites to remain in tact.